# Turn based multiplayer, Google services or Parse or..

Tags: android, turn-based, google-play

I have a turn based game on Google play already (paid with around 2000 users and free with around 50k).i am thinking of adding multiplier option to it. I am unable to progress because I don't know which path to take (given its my first multiplier game). I need your help

Like any turn based app, you have the concept of players joining in, rooms, scores and ranking (linking it with fb is preferred) 
For my backend server, which option should I go with? Google play game services, Parse, AppWrap.. Etc or simply me use my website server and do the server code?

I am leaning towards Google Game services just because the infrastructure is there and it's free. But I don't find it to provide flexibility and control (such as using nicknames, listing rooms.. Etc)

I just heard about Parse so no experience

Any help or recommendations? Plzzzz need your advice

Comment: Do you mean "multiplayer"?

Comment: Oops yes, this damn autocorrect replaced it. Its Multiplayer that I meant

Comment: Hi @Snake any update on this question? It would be more helpful if you share your experience with above question. Thanks.